# How to auto-adjust intersection plane in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, intersection, plane

I have a slice plane to cut the object. Currently, the slice plane is either infinite or I have to manually adjust its size. I want to auto-adjust the size of the slice plane according to the size of intersection planes. I've add a figure for demonstration. I've done a lot of searches and try but still have no idea. Can anyone give some hints or help? I don't want to use Shaders, I need the actual plane.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzmoZ.png)

Comment: so in other words you want to get the intersection mesh with exactly the form of the intersection between a 3D model and a plane?

Comment: @derHugo Yes exactly

Comment: So like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114055/calculate-edge-loop-from-plane-intersection) ?

Comment: @derHugo, wow seems great! I will check this. Thank you!